# Create a random, but most frequently in a certain range

Tags: java, random, numbers

I have to create a certain task that simulates the systolic pressure of a person, so i tried this:

```
rand = new Random();
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
    Integer sbp = rand.nextInt((130 - 80) + 1) + 80;
        lblSBPCounter.setText(Integer.toString(sbp));           
}
}, 1000, 120000);
```

The problem is that the systolic pressure has a range from 90 to 120. If it goes below 90 or above 120, that person is in trouble. So in the code i tried to generate a random number every 2 minutes from 80 to 130. The problem is that the random function goes pretty often under and above the range. So my question is: Can i make the function generate more numbers from 90 to 120 and less numbers under 90 and above 120? Like 1 number every 1-2 hours?

Comment: Try picking a number from a normal distribution.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Random.nextGaussian() method. I chose 105 and 10 for the mean and standard deviation, so less than 0.3% of results from this example will be below 90 or above 120. I also added a piece to regenerate the number if it falls outside of your 80 to 130 range.

```
rand = new Random();
timer = new Timer();
int mean = 105, standardDeviation = 5;
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
    Integer sbp;
    do
    {
        sbp = (int) Math.round((rand.nextGaussian() * standardDeviation) + mean);
    } 
    while(sbp < 80 || sbp > 130)

    lblSBPCounter.setText(Integer.toString(sbp));           
}
}, 1000, 120000);
```

If you (or someone coming across this question) don't know how to choose a standard deviation, the rule is that 68.27% of results will fall within one standard deviation of the mean, 95.45% of the results are within 2 SDs, and 99.73% of results are within 3 SDs.

**Edit:** I forgot to include Math.round() and had mean and standard deviation switched around.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following and you can put your lower and upper bounds

```
public void usingThreadLocalClass() {
        int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(80, 130);
        System.out.println("Random number generated is : " + randomInt);
       }
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and normal rand? i do not obtain better results :(

Comment: Random.nextInt(int n) : The nextInt(int n) is used to get a random number between 0(inclusive) and the number passed in this argument(n), exclusive. From what i can tell your code will generate a number between 0 and up to 51+80

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question, are you wanting to selected a random number from a weighted distribution?

Answer (score 0):

While in general answer making it gaussian looks to be working, I could tell you that systolic pressure distribution is NOT gaussian - it is not symmetric, it does have somewhat fat tail.

You could try to simulate it with log-normal, f.e., python code

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

x = np.linspace(77.0, 227.0, 151)
ax.plot(x, lognorm.pdf(x, s=.5, loc=77.0, scale=36.0), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='gamma pdf')
```

will produce graph

[image]

which looks like empirical data from [here](http://ecp.acponline.org/marapr99/changing_fg3.htm). Basically, there is rather sharp bound at lower end (I guessed it to be 77, below that is just not possible to live), with fat tail up to circa +200, people known to live (not very long but still) with very high systolic pressure.

So, if you have to sample log-normal distribution in Java, you could use [Apache common math library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/LogNormalDistribution.html).

Along the lines (some Java, untested)

```
double m = 0.0;
double s = 0.5;

LogNormalDistribution lnd = new LogNormalDistribution(m, s);
double r = lnd.sample();
return r*36.0 + 77.0;
```